# Реализация индексации в хэш-таблице на основе хэш-значений полученных с помощью md5 алгоритма

Tags: c++, алгоритм, хеширование, структуры-данных, md5

1. Объясните, как реализовать индексацию в хэш-таблице, если хэш-значение не имеет целочисленного вида? Используется хэш-функция на основе md5 алгоритма.
2. Как определить размер памяти, которую нужно выделить под хэш-таблицу?

Comment: Значит, нужен хэш для хэша :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте степень двойки для размера своей хэш-таблицы и берите младшие биты MD5 для индексации.

Естественно, для разрешения коллизий весь 128-бит MD5 придется хранить вместе с адресуемыми им данными.